# Average property price per country?

Tags: real-estate, prices

Where can I find the average price of properties in each country? I know prices vary from city to city but I was hoping there was something for each country much like for the UK ([link](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices/bulletins/housepriceindex/july2021#:%7E:text=Image%20.csv%20.xls-,The%20average%20UK%20house%20price%20was%20%C2%A3256%2C000%20in%20July,same%20period%20a%20year%20ago.))

Comment: i think here ......................................................................................
https://www.numbeo.com/property-investment/rankings_by_country.jsp

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. That's an index unfortunately. Apartment prices on the website are provided per square meter which won't work.